# Excel, COUNTIF & LEFT (Only look at first 6 characters)

Tags: excel-formula

This formula searches across the entire column B for the value in cell A2. If no match is found, the formula returns "No match in B", an empty string otherwise:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "")`

How can I make it do the same thing, but only use the first 6 characters to match (format is kinda like this **467584-Blue-Red-White**)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LEFT` formula. Something like (original answer edited):

`=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,LEFT($A2,6)&"*"),"No match in B","")`

Comment: This seems to result in No match in B for all even where there is a match.  When I remove the LEFT part it will then show as empty where there is a match.

Comment: change `LEFT($A2,6)` to `LEFT($A2,6)&"*"`